# CMS with HTML and PDF view

Tags: html, scala, templates, pdf, content-management-system

I develop a website to create and export PDF view, so I need a CMS to create template with below features

- Integrate with website develop by Scala, Java...
- Admin will create a template with pattern. For example: Dear [#name] ==> [#name] will be replaced by value from database
- Generate HTML based on template to review
- Generate PDF to download

Currently, I use Latex but it is not an good CMS and do not have HTML preview. Please suggest me other CMS

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: @AlexisWilke: But this is not create as pattern template

Comment: It's really not that difficult to do a search and replace (`preg_replace()` in PHP for example) ahead of time, before passing the HTML to the PDF tool. My CMS has a filter plugin that does that with advanced tokens that support parameters and recursivity, but to get started, you certainly do not need to go that far. 8-)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Currently, I use Latex but it is not an good CMS and do not have HTML preview, so I want to found an editor that can load template, view as HTML and export the pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my [own CMS](http://snapwebsites.org/), but it's C++ and does not have a PDF converter as is per se.

However, you may be interested by the [pisa project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa), which is an HTML to PDF converter that understands a lot of HTML and CSS. There are limits as you will see if you try it, but I think that in most situations you can relatively easily tweak the source (HTML/CSS) so the conversion works as expected.

So any CMS you like that does everything you need except PDF may be tweaked so PDF ends up working as per your specification.